# How to serve Vue data from Django backend?

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, vuejs2

So I am trying to use Vue & Django with django-webpack-loader (not DRF), but I'm just getting stuck whenever I try to actually feed Vue data. I am just trying to convert a static Django template to a (.vue) Vue template but I'm not sure how Vue is meant to handle that data?

I'm under the impression that you do something along the lines of this in the script tags:

```
  new Vue ({
    data: function () {
      game: {{game}}
    } 
  });
```

And then reference this with `{{game.title}}` etc in the main html of the Vue template, using Django `{% verbatim %}` tags so they don't interfere right?

But this just doesn't do anything, Django doesn't give Vue anything and I just get `error  'game:' is defined but never used` and  `error  'game' is not defined`. I'm just not sure where to go from here and I just need some sort of help...

Comment: may be this could help https://vsupalov.com/vue-js-in-django-template/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly that you're trying to have Django directly serve *.vue Single File Components (SFC), then I don't know of anyway that could work.  These files will need to be separate from Django so that Vue/webpack can build them into JS.

But there is another way to integrate Django Templates with Vue SFCs. I (humbly) recommend reading my series of articles starting with [Vue + Django — Best of Both Frontends](https://medium.com/js-dojo/vue-django-best-of-both-frontends-701307871478). This will walk you through all the steps to do so, freely mixing Django Templates and Vue SFC wherever/whenever you deem appropriate.

There's a [companion repo](https://github.com/ilikerobots/django-vue-mpa) with a ready made Django+Vue starter app.

Otherwise, if I've misunderstood your intention, please clarify so we can better answer.

Comment: Wow did not expect you to reply to this! Those articles are exactly the series I've found so helpful - I just got a bit confused on actual database connection but I'm sure I just misunderstood some sections of your articles. Thanks for the response :)

Comment: You're very welcome.  Feel free to add an issue or email me if something is unclear in the articles.  To clarify data passing from Django template variable -> Vue: it must be done on the template page loading the Vue entry page (see https://github.com/ilikerobots/django-vue-mpa/blob/master/templates/fully_lazy.html#L14).  Other than this, the Vue code has no visibility into Django data.  For more complex info from your Django backend, then communicating via Rest (e.g. Axios -> DRF) is recommended.

Comment: Ahh, damn. I was hoping to get away without using DRF. That's fine though I have played with it in the past so I should be okay. I may have to take you up on a bit of help at some point though!